# Infinite loop in a JPanel

Tags: java, eclipse, jframe, jpanel

I want to program a simple Snake.
Therefore I have programmed a custom `JPanel`, which can hold a `Scene`.
A `Scene` just draws something, and you can thread it with the `public void run()` method, so it implements `Runnable`.

Now, when I initialise the Scene, I create a `Thread` of the instance.

```
if (this.getThread() == null) {
    Thread sceneThread = new Thread(this);
    this.setThread(sceneThread);
    this.getThread().run();
} else {
    System.err.println("Scene is already running");
}
```

And the scene finally begins to be executed in a separate thread:

```
// Run thread
public void run () {
    try {
        while (true) {
            this.update();
            this.getGamePanel().sceneShouldRepaint();

            Thread.sleep(this.getFps());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

Somehow this is blocking the windows thread.
It does not appear anymore.

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: can you give the code for the windows thread ?

Comment: Have you read and understood how the swing threading model works with the event dispatch thread? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html

Comment: @IshanKhanna I just create a JFrame `new GUI();`, `GUI` is a `JFrame` subclass

Comment: @Qwerky No, I actually haven't, I'll take a look at it.
So, the thread where I create it is waiting until the new thread is done?

Comment: @NSAddict - hard to say without seeing more of your code. I guess you are either blocking the EDT or updating the UI off the EDT.

Comment: @Qwerky it was the `this.getThread().run();`, I had to run `.start()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are *not* starting the thread but directly invoke its `run` method, thus you are blocking the event thread itself in an endless loop - try *starting* it by calling `start()` instead.

Plus be sure to read about multithreading in Swing applications as pointed out by Qwerky.